# scrapy item can not writing to mysql

Tags: mysql, scrapy

I am using scrapy to crawl some images and I want to store the info into mysql.there are some fields in my item, when I write the item to mysql, everything is ok, but one field can not write to mysql, the field in mysql table is empty.
the item:

```
class ProductItem(scrapy.Item):
    brand = scrapy.Field()      
    series = scrapy.Field()     
    commodity = scrapy.Field()  
    designer = scrapy.Field()   
    year = scrapy.Field()       
    description = scrapy.Field()  
    url = scrapy.Field()  
    name = scrapy.Field()
```

the pipeline:

```
class MySQLPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        host = 'localhost'
        user = 'root'
        passwd = '123456'
        db = 'haijuhui'

        self.db = MySQLdb.connect(host=host, user=user, passwd=passwd, db=db)
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        pp('============================')
        pp(item['description'])
        pp('============================')
        fields = ''
        values = ''
        for k, v in item.items():
            fields += k + ','
            values += "'" + v + "'" + ','
        fields = fields[0:-1]
        values = values[0:-1]

        insert_sql = "INSERT INTO product (%s) values (%s)" % (fields, values)
        self.cursor.execute(insert_sql)
        self.db.commit()

        return item
```

the print of the pipeline:

```
    '============================'
    u'\r\n                        Butterfly gets its name from the \u201cbutterfly\u201d shape created by the outer corner that joins the armrest and the backrest. It is a modular seating system that responds effectively to the needs of modularity and comfort, suitable for free and informal usage. Its modular structure is shaped around an ottoman, which is the base piece, and which, when integrated with the backrest and/or the armrest, becomes a central or terminal element, either left or right. The combination of these elements, using a simple joint system, makes it possible to freely set up versatile configurations, from in-line sofas to corner solutions, from front-facing to lounge layouts. This first textile sofa in B&B Italia Outdoor collection is characterised by soft and sinuous shapes. Completely upholstered, it leverages the company\u2019s production technology, with materials and solutions designed for outdoor use, in order to take outdoors the quality and comfort that has always characterized indoor seating. The system includes a family of complements, small tables and consoles, seamlessly integrated with the seats, making it possible to design many compositions suitable for different space customization requirements. The strong material component of Butterfly\u2019s cover and the softness of its shapes are an invitation to comfort, which, together with the modularity of the system, make it ideal for transversal projects, from hotels to marine applications.\r\n                    '
    '============================'
........
```

the insert sql:

```
u"INSERT INTO product (designer,description,commodity,url,series,brand,year,name) values ('PATRICIA URQUIOLA','\r\n                        Butterfly gets its name from the \u201cbutterfly\u201d shape created by the outer corner that joins the armrest and the backrest. It is a modular seating system that responds effectively to the needs of modularity and comfort, suitable for free and informal usage. Its modular structure is shaped around an ottoman, which is the base piece, and which, when integrated with the backrest and/or the armrest, becomes a central or terminal element, either left or right. The combination of these elements, using a simple joint system, makes it possible to freely set up versatile configurations, from in-line sofas to corner solutions, from front-facing to lounge layouts. This first textile sofa in B&B Italia Outdoor collection is characterised by soft and sinuous shapes. Completely upholstered, it leverages the company\u2019s production technology, with materials and solutions designed for outdoor use, in order to take outdoors the quality and comfort that has always characterized indoor seating. The system includes a family of complements, small tables and consoles, seamlessly integrated with the seats, making it possible to design many compositions suitable for different space customization requirements. The strong material component of Butterfly\u2019s cover and the softness of its shapes are an invitation to comfort, which, together with the modularity of the system, make it ideal for transversal projects, from hotels to marine applications.\r\n                    ','SOFAS','http://www.bebitalia.com/App_Uploads/Prodotti/0385/Gallery/big-01-OUTDOOR-BUTTERFLY-BUTTERFLY_01.jpg,http://www.bebitalia.com/App_Uploads/Prodotti/0385/Gallery/big-02-OUTDOOR-BUTTERFLY-BUTTERFLY_02.jpg,http://www.bebitalia.com/App_Uploads/Prodotti/0385/Gallery/big-03-OUTDOOR-BUTTERFLY-BUTTERFLY_03.jpg,http://www.bebitalia.com/App_Uploads/Prodotti/0385/Gallery/big-04-OUTDOOR-BUTTERFLY-BUTTERFLY_04.jpg,http://www.bebitalia.com/App_Uploads/Prodotti/0385/Gallery/big-05-OUTDOOR-BUTTERFLY-BUTTERFLY_05.jpg,http://www.bebitalia.com/App_Uploads/Prodotti/0385/Gallery/big-06-OUTDOOR-BUTTERFLY-BUTTERFLY_06.jpg,http://www.bebitalia.com/App_Uploads/Prodotti/0385/Gallery/big-07-OUTDOOR-BUTTERFLY-BUTTERFLY_07.jpg,http://www.bebitalia.com/App_Uploads/Prodotti/0385/Gallery/big-08-OUTDOOR-BUTTERFLY-BUTTERFLY_08.jpg,http://www.bebitalia.com/App_Uploads/Prodotti/0385/Gallery/big-09-OUTDOOR-BUTTERFLY-BUTTERFLY_09.jpg,http://www.bebitalia.com/App_Uploads/Prodotti/0385/Gallery/big-10-OUTDOOR-BUTTERFLY-BUTTERFLY_10.jpg','BUTTERFLY','B&B Italia Outdoor','2015','BUTTERFLY - PHOTO GALLERY - 1,BUTTERFLY - PHOTO GALLERY - 2,BUTTERFLY - PHOTO GALLERY - 3,BUTTERFLY - PHOTO GALLERY - 4,BUTTERFLY - PHOTO GALLERY - 5,BUTTERFLY - PHOTO GALLERY - 6,BUTTERFLY - PHOTO GALLERY - 7,BUTTERFLY - PHOTO GALLERY - 8,BUTTERFLY - PHOTO GALLERY - 9,BUTTERFLY - PHOTO GALLERY - 10')"
```

as the jkavalik's comment, when execute the statement **select description, hex(description) from product**,the description is not empty, and its value is as following:

```
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
```

the mysql table

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| brand       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| series      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| commodity   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| designer    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| year        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| url         | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name        | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

all the field value can inserted into the table except the description field.
I can not find what causes this, please help me..

Comment: is it possible that you must Quote 'text text' the content to escape the spaces and other special chars in the text

Comment: Output/log the generated insert statement somewhere so you can check it and try to run it in mysql client to see any errors and warnings. Note: creating sql query by string concatenation is potentially vulnerable to sql injection. In your case it is not direct user input, but still someone migth prepare image malicious properties in the way of your crawler.

Comment: @jkavalik I print the insert statement and execute it in mysql client.it can works and no warnings,but the field is still empty just as the scrapy work

Comment: @BerndBuffen can you describe it clearly?

Comment: @tudouya and can you add the insert to your question? As you concatenate the string, some quoting is happening and if we can look at it, someone might spot the reason.

Comment: @jkavalik I edit my question, please see the insert sql..

Comment: @tudouya can you do `select description, hex(description) from product` ? if the field is really empty, then hex(description) should be empty too - if it is not, then you might see some binary data - wrong charset might be a reason for text being truncated.

Comment: @jkavalik, you are right, hex(description) is not empty.my schema and table charset is utf-8. so i don't know what is the problem.

Comment: @tudouya so add the output of hex() too - it contains the stored data in hexadecimal encoding, so you should be able to decode what each byte contains

Comment: @jkavalik I edited the quesiton again, please check it

Comment: If you put that hex string into http://string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx or similar function, it returns the actual text, so the field contains what you inserted.. The problem seems to be on selecting or showing it - the text starts with a newline and some whitespace, is it possible that you do not see it because you only get the empty first line?

Comment: @jkavalik, I trid the tool, it return the actual text ..